# BigQuery field candidate to guarantee consistent LIMIT/OFFSET results

Tags: google-bigquery

It's not a secret that BigQuery doesn't guarantee any order when using limiting/offsetting.
I don't have unique identifiers or timestamps to apply a default order by clause.

Is there any trick for consistent behavior when pagination is required?

To be more specific, the complete query is dynamic and depends on the user input. The user might use pagination and not specify any columns to be used in ORDER BY.

In this case, the results from the table must be deterministic otherwise the pagination
doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You need to enforce an order, e.g. by using an additional column and sort by this one. `farm_fingerprint(col1 || col2 || col3)` generates an unique value from several columns and should not be that big of an over head. Another way could be the generation of a `create temp table` and query this one several times with different offsets.

Comment: @Samuel, thank you for commenting. Problem is, this query is formed in a dynamic fashion so the set of `col1, col2, col3` is unknown beforehand

Comment: Can your force a wrapper over the user SQL? `SELECT farm_fingerprint(TO_JSON_STRING(Allcust)), *,

from(
Select 1 as a , 2 as b
) as Allcust
order by 1 limit 100`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that using BigQuery jobs.query + jobs.getQueryResults API:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query

1. (optional) Specify maxResults if you'd like to limit the number of rows returned. Otherwise, responses will be limited to 10Mb.
2. In the response, you will have "pageToken" field. If "pageToken" is not specified - you are done, all rows have been returned already. If not, use pageToken and jobId to fetch more rows using jobs.getQueryResults.
3. Continue calling jobs.getQueryResults as needed for more pages.